# Pandas, Python, Excel, Bold a row using conditional formatting no solution

Tags: python, pandas, bold

I am using python3 and pandas to create a script to:

- Read unstructured xsls data of varing column lengths
- Total the "this", "last" and "diff" columns
- Add Total under the brands columns
- Dynamically bold the entire row that contains "total"

On the last point, the challenge I have been struggling with is that the row index changes depending on the data being fed in to the script. The code provided does not have a solution to this issue. I have tried every variation I can think of using `style.applymap(bold)` with and without variables.

Example of input
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHgvn.png)

Example of desired outcome

[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUXUf.png)

Script:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
import sys
import warnings

def bold(val):

    return 'font-weight: bold'

excel_file = 'testfile1.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

product = (df.loc[df['Brand'] == "widgit"])
product = product.append({'Brand':'Total',
                          'This':product['This'].sum(),
                          'Last':product['Last'].sum(),
                          'Diff':product['Diff'].sum(),
                          '% Chg':product['This'].sum()/product['Last'].sum()
                         },
                         ignore_index=True)
product = product.append({'Brand':' '}, ignore_index=True)

product.fillna(' ', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this:

```
def highlight_max(x):
    return ['font-weight: bold' if v == x.loc[4] else ''
                for v in x]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2))
df.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and report back.

Comment: I tried it out and it partially worked. as long as x.loc[4]  is set to the row that contains the total it does work however this script must be able to process imput data that will have variable row lengths. If possible the style apply would find any row that contains Total and apply bold to the entire line without a fixed loc line. ty

Comment: So I have modified your answer to  

def bold(x):
    return ['font-weight: bold' if v == 'Total' or v == 'Grand Total' else '' 
                for v in x] 

Which bolds all Totals and the grand total but does not do the entire row for each total. Thoughts?

Comment: can you send me your dataset to my mail or anywhere else you can?

Comment: I wish I could however the dataset is confidential. For all intents and purposes you have answered the question correctly and I thank you.